# Is possible recover repair an file with missing metadata?

Tags: btrfs

Thanks for reading my topic.
In an BTRFS partition is possible read or repair an file having missing or damaged own metada ?

Have an nice week.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Can you please be more specific? What type of file, what type of metadata, what about the metadata is missing or damaged, how was (or what caused) the file or metadata (to become) corrupted, damaged, or missing? Thanks.

Comment: Also, do you have any BTRFS snapshots? If so, have you already tried rolling back to a previous snapshot from when the file was not damaged?